# Is it possible to deploy Spring application in SCDF 2.10?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

If I have  Spring batch jobs bundled within a Spring (Spring version 5.3)application (not a Springboot), Would I still be able to deploy in SCDF-2.10 server, by registering each of these jobs as tasks ? Will this work? Would I be able to register these Spring apps as 'App' in Data flow server? And could  I still be able to use Data flow Shell , to register them?

Have already tested Springboot applications on SCDF server by registering as Tasks, but did not find any info on Spring Applications

Answer (score 0):

The SCDF ecosystem was designed around Spring Boot applications. However there is support for [polyglot](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/recipes/polyglot/) applications.

If the application is packaged in a container and registered as a task, the container will be launched.

If you want it to be visible as a Task then it should include Spring Cloud Task 2.4.x with properties to access the SCDF datasource. These will be provided in the same format as expected by a Spring Boot application.